# DIAB internal constant generated by Windriver compiler

Tags: c, memory-management, embedded

In my software, I have memory sections (user defined) where my variable/code stored . 
but I have warning that some constants cannot be stored in user defined section.

After some debugging i find out that the Windriver compiler generates some constant "DIAB internal generated constants" and this constant cannot be stored in the user defined section

Can anyone please help me to understand what is 
**internal constants generated by the compiler.**

Comment: It might help if you could provide more information. User defined sections are not part of the C language; they are probably an extension defined by your compiler. Please specify what platform you are developing for and what compiler (windriver?) you are using. Also try to provide some example code that exhibits the problem you are facing.

Comment: I am working on MPC565 processor with  Non-volatile memory, where I defined the particular sections of memory shall contains the particular code. Now my problem is there is Internal constant generated by compiler (windriver diab 5.9.1 ) where I am facing a problem  to defined in predefined sections.

Comment: **I am tring to understand what is this internal gernated constanst **

Comment: Can you please show me code that causes these internal generated constants to be generated?

Comment: The *constants* may need to be read/write or execute.  It would be helpful to get a section listing of the objects you are trying to link.  It is difficult for anyone to give help with a proprietary compiler; you best bet is WindRiver support.

Comment: I know that many embedded compilers generate internal constants when they optimize large switch-case statements into jump-tables. This optimization is most of the time also very inefficient so it's not uncommon to see huge ROM consumption in the "internal constants" area. I'm not sure whether the last such problem I encountered was with Windriver of GreenHills. But for sure if you have a lot of switch-cases then it might be the reason in your case.